# Bounce effect on a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, easing

I have an `UIScrollView` with content in. I what to create a bounce effect on the content of the view.

For all the animations of this app, I use [zrxq Easing functions](https://github.com/zrxq/UIView-EasingFunctions/).

Here is my current code :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.6 
    animations:^{
        [_buttonScrollView setEasingFunction:BounceEaseIn forKeyPath:@"bounds"];
        _buttonScrollView.bounds = 
           CGRectModify(_buttonScrollView.bounds, 
                        0, 
                        CGRectGetMidY(_buttonScrollView.bounds) / 2, 
                        0, 
                        0);
    } 

    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [_buttonScrollView removeEasingFunctionForKeyPath:@"bounds"];
    }    
];
```

The problem with this code is that the position of my content in the final state will not be the same as his position on initial state.

I've tried to put an other animation in the `completionBlock` to move back the content but there is a little pause between the two animations.

I've also tried with [this solution](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/lets-bounce/) but I want to put the bounce effect on the content, not on the `UIScrollView` and the method `addAnimation:animation forKey:@"jumping"` must be applied on a layer and I don't think the whole content of my `UIScrollView` have a layer property.

My app need to work on `IOS6` so I can't use `UIKit Dynamics`.

Comment: "My app need to work on `IOS6` so I can't use `UIKit`" – UIKit is available on all iOS versions, all the way back to iOS 2.0 (the first version with an SDK). `UIScrollView` is part of `UIKit`. Do you mean `UIKit Dynamics`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom class for bouncy effect.

Refer this link https://github.com/antoniocasero/ACPScrollMenu on github.